# NSLineBreakByWordWrapping not working ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, line-breaks, word-wrap

I have a UILabel which is populated from the database .. the text in the UILabel can be long and can be short .. the problem is that the text is being cut at the end .. 
for example its shown like this: 
"www.sample.com/h1/h2/h3..." 
where it should be: "www.sample.com/h1/h2/h3/h4/h5/h6.html"

This is the code I am using:

```
CGFloat constraintWidth = 180.0f;

CGSize labelsize = [details.web sizeWithFont:self.webTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constraintWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(20, self.webTitleLabel.frame.origin.y + self.WebTitleLabel.frame.size.height + 10, constraintWidth, labelsize.height);

[self.webLabel setFrame:webFrame];

[self.webLabel setText:details.web]; // details.web is where I get it from the database

self.webLabel .numberOfLines=0;
```

I am using Xcode 5 and iOS 7

**SOLVED:**
I managed to solve it using this method:

```
UILabel *instructions = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 225, 300, 180)];
   NSString *text = @"First take clear picture and then try to zoom in to fit the ";
   instructions.text = text;
   instructions.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
   instructions.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
   [instructions setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

   CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:instructions.font 
                                constrainedToSize:instructions.frame.size
                                    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect newFrame = instructions.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    instructions.frame = newFrame;
    instructions.numberOfLines = 0;
    [instructions sizeToFit];
    [self addSubview:instructions];
```

Comment: Use NSLineBreakByCharWrapping, else set the label width dynamically.

Comment: @EriK I tried NSLineBreakByCharWrapping still the same result

Comment: where you used "NSLineBreakByCharWrapping"?

Comment: You have to do in both places,  `CGSize labelsize = [details.web sizeWithFont:self.webTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constraintWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];`  and  `self.webLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`.

Comment: in the labelsize .. instead of NSLineBreakByWordWrapping I changed it to NSLineBreakByCharWrapping and also in the .xib I changed the label line mode to char wrapping and still the same

Comment: try to set programmatically for label

Comment: @Erik I tried its gives me 2 lines but still cuts the last few words

Comment: setNumberOfLines:0 fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use following to get dynamic size of your text or label

```
 labelHeight = [details.web boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(constraintWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSLineBreakByWordWrapping attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.webTextLabel.font} context:nil];
```

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary : can you put your crash log here ?